# firebase token html , javascript how to integrate it all in andriod webview

Tags: java, android, html, firebase

ok i got this script working in registration form using html and javascript as shown below. works fine in webbrowsers no issues. when i open the page using android webview it seems like it does not fire up no token has been retrieved at the initial load.

any insights is appreciated!

```
<script src="https://www.website/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.website/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script>
 const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
  authDomain: "YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN",
  projectId: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID",
  storageBucket: "YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET",
  messagingSenderId: "YOUR_SENDER_ID",
  appId: "YOUR_APP_ID",
  measurementId: "YOUR_MEASUREMENT_ID"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Retrieve FCM token and set it in the hidden field
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

// Service worker registration
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
navigator.serviceWorker.register('firebase-messaging-sw.js')
  .then((registration) => {
    console.log('Service Worker registered:', registration);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Service Worker registration failed:', err);
  });
 }

 messaging.getToken().then(token => {
// Set the token value in the hidden input field
document.getElementById('fcmToken').value = token;
 }).catch(error => {
  // Handle token generation failure
   console.error('Error getting FCM token:', error);
 });
</script>
```

Comment: How are you loading the Firebase SDK?  The code `firebase.initializeApp()` and `firebase.messaging()` is using the older "namespaced API" syntax rather than the newer "modular API" syntax that came out with v9 of the Client SDK.